# Problems with mixpanel and a tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, mixpanel

So I have the following line of code

```
<a href="/creator/"><button onclick='mixpanel.track("Get Started Clicked")'>Get started</button></a>
```

But while it goes to the link it never manages to send the event to mixpanel. I've tried a few tests, mainly putting in a different function such as

```
<a href="/creator/"><button onclick='console.log("Button clicked")'>Get started</button></a>
```

Which works. I've even tried variants such as

```
<button onclick='mixpanel.track("Get Started Clicked");window.location="/creator/"'>Get started</button>
```

Which still doesn't work. The only time I've gotten the event to be tracked was when it was JUST the mixpanel call and no page change. Does anyone know why this might be the case? How to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. It was quite simple. The mixpanel track() function is asynchronous and I'm guessing the window location change happened before it could complete whatever it was suppose to do (mainly, before it could send the event to the mixpanel servers).

I solved it, by looking again at the documentation and realizing I could pass in a callback function.

When I saw that including a callback was an optional parameter, I should have guessed it was an async action. Oh well, now I (and anyone else curious) knows